# Database initialization strategy Code First

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have an `ASP.NET-MVC` application with `Migration` enabled and `SimpleMemberShipProvider` configured to use my database with some extra tables/fields.

My question is, where to put my database initialization? Because i'm still developing it, i'm okay with dropping the database/tables and data and recreate it.

I have put it in the configuration.cs file, but i'm not sure if that's the place for the database initializer.

```
namespace CFContext.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using WebMatrix.WebData;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DataContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>());
        //Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataContext>());
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //

        SeedMembership(context);
    }

    private void SeedMembership(DataContext context)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

        var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
        var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider;

        if (!roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
            roles.CreateRole("Administrator");

        if (membership.GetUser("Username0", false) == null)
        {

        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class ContextInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Context>
{     
    private static void InitializeWebSecurity()
    {
        if (WebSecurity.Initialized)
            return;

        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
            connectionStringName: "DefaultConnection",
            userTableName: "User",
            userIdColumn: "Id",
            userNameColumn: "Email",
            autoCreateTables: true);

        Roles.CreateRole("Admin");
        Roles.CreateRole("Customer");
    }       

    protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        InitializeWebSecurity();

        // more seeding
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        DatabaseConfig.RegisterDatabase();
        AutoMapperConfig.RegisterConfig();

        // Set the initializer here
        Database.SetInitializer(new ContextInitializer());

        // Now initialize it
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            context.Database.Initialize(false);
        }

        // Double check seeding has initalized, if not
        // We initialize it here to make sure.
        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
        {
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
                connectionStringName: "DefaultConnection", 
                userTableName: "User", 
                userIdColumn: "Id", 
                userNameColumn: "Email", 
                autoCreateTables: false);
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to create migrations the same way with this setup.

Comment: Hi, the confusing part here is that, if you enable migrations, the configuration.cs file already has a protected override void Seed(Context context) method. Is it okay to have it on multiple places?

Comment: You should only set one initialization strategy, so CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Context> should not be in yours. Just make sure you set the initialization strategy to use your Migrations setup. Having two different Types should not affect it.

Comment: I meant just the Seed() method which is also in the configuration.cs when migrations is enabled. I would have the Seed() method twice.

Comment: But the seed method would only be called by the Configuration.cs because that's the initialization strategy you've chosen. If you chose CreateDatabaseIfNotExists, that seed function would be called instead.

Comment: So it's okay to have the Seed() method twice? I have updated my question with the contents of configuration.cs

Answer (score 5):

put your database initialization code into "**Application_Start**" method on ***Global.asax***

Comment: Hi, what happens if i exec 'Update-Database' command in the NuGet console? Will it look in the Global.asax too?

Comment: It should know once you compile the assembly, what needs to happen.

Comment: I have migrations enabled in a class library. I separated the database operations from the web project.

Comment: That's how i do mine too. Then I reference my "Database" project on my MVC Project.

Answer (score 0):

I put it inside the Application_Start in Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Name of Connection String", "User Table in DataBase", "UserId Column", "UserName Column", true);
        }
```

The true, means that I want to autoCreate the tables.

In Web.config file, you need to setup the provider:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />

    <membership defaultProvider="nameProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="nameProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider,WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
```

It works for me.